# Usage of word "withheld"

Tags: word-usage, legalese

I'm reading this one website [insurance of employees](http://www.etera.fi/en/pension-insurance/tyel-employees/when-should-an-employee-be-insured) and got confused.

> The employee's portion of the insurance contribution is withheld from the employee's pay

So does it mean, the employee's insurance will be covered by employer, or it will be deducted from the salary?

Comment: @Josh61 So fast. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @Mystery Typically, insurance is a benefit employers offer to attract good employees. The employer pays for a large portion of the cost of the insurance (that is, quite literally, the *benefit*), but not the *entire* cost. The employee still must pay some. Since the benefit (once elected) is not optional and must be paid in full, the remaining cost (the employee's share of the cost) is deducted automatically from his pay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Withheld" means that an amount of money that would otherwise be due the employee is kept by the employer, to (partially) pay for the insurance.  In the US employers "withhold" tax money on behalf of the government, and also may "withhold" money to pay an employee's medical insurance.  One may also have money voluntarily "withheld" to deposit into a savings account.

In the case of medical insurance, the employer may choose to pay the entire cost, with nothing withheld from the employee's pay (*), or may only pay some portion of the cost, withholding the rest from the employee's pay.

(*) It used to be quite common (up until about 1980) for US employers to pay the entire amount for medical insurance, but they've gotten stingier over the years, and it's now common for the employer to "contribute" less than half of the total cost.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the insurance [premium] is paid for jointly by the company and the employee.
This is often done for ease of processing, and streamlining payments to the insurance company

keeping this in mind.. and coming to answer your question...
the employee's insurance will be covered by employer,:: Partially[ why else is it withholding "employee's portion of the insurance contribution" the other part is of course paid for by the company]
or 
it will be deducted from the salary? :: Yes [which will then be transferred to the insurance company/body]